# How to select Distinct char data type and convert into int by casting using sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have saved `Company_Code` in `Company` table as `char` data type. Now, I want to retrieve the `Company_Code` as an `integer` data type as `DISTINCT` (no values should repeat) and in the form of an `Integer` array.

I am using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Company_Code 
FROM Company  
ORDER BY CAST(Company_Code AS INT);
```

This code shows the following error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Kindly let me know that if it is possible?

Or if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You could exchange `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Company_Code 
FROM Company 
GROUP BY Company_Code 
ORDER By Cast(Company_Code as int);
         -- if it is possible that CAST will fail, then you should use TRY_CAST
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LUGL42715)**

More info: [How SQL DISTINCT and ORDER BY are Related](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/07/13/how-sql-distinct-and-order-by-are-related/)

Comment: What to do if I want to add a condition too?

Comment: @TahaWaseem Then please add another question.